# Select2 cambia de tamaño

Tags: select2

Estoy utilizando el select2 en mi pagina pero al momento de utlizar otro componente  los select2 cambian de tamaño dentro de los tabs, al inicio se muestra de esta manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el siguiente Tabs los tamaños de los select2 cambian
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
 .. podrian ayudarme con esto por favor 
Gracias

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow! Vanessa, te recomiendo que adjuntes tu codigo a tu pregunta, para que asi cualquier usuario que te pueda ayudar, pueda de una manera facil, reproducir el problema y darte una solucion, basta con hacer clic en **[editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/111755/edit)** y adjuntar tu codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Ya intentaste poner `width:100%` al elemento con la clase `select2-container`? Por supuesto, teniendo en cuenta que los elementos padre de los demás inputs parece que por defecto tienen esa propiedad.

Comment: Gracias esa fue la solución  :)